# Can I add properties to an object created by a jQuery prototype?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
 var $form = '',
    $modal = '',
    $submits = ''; 

 function createModal() {
        $modal = $.modal({
            title: title,
            closeButton: true,
            content: content,
            resizeOnLoad: true
        });
        $form = $modal.find('.form');
        $message = $modal.find('.message');
        $submits = $modal.find('.submit-button');
        href = $form.attr('data-href');
    }
```

Is there some way that I could add $form, $message and $submits to the $modal object as they are all related.

Comment: You can add properties to any object that hasn't been sealed or frozen.

Comment: But are the result of .find properties ?

Comment: The result of `.find()` will be jQuery objects. So they're values that can be added to properties of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To associate data to a jQuery object, you may use the [data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function :

> The jQuery.data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM
>   elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore
>   free from memory leaks. jQuery ensures that the data is removed when
>   DOM elements are removed via jQuery methods, and when the user leaves
>   the page. We can set several distinct values for a single element and
>   retrieve them later:
>
> - jQuery.data(document.body, 'foo', 52);
> - jQuery.data(document.body, 'bar', 'test');

You usually need this because simply associate some properties to a jQuery object wouldn't allow you to get the data back from another object wrapping the same element.

In your case, if you keep a reference to your object, you may simply do

```
 function createModal() {
    var $modal = $.modal({
        title: title,
        closeButton: true,
        content: content,
        resizeOnLoad: true
    });
    return {
        $modal   : $modal,
        $form    : $modal.find('.form'),
        $message : $modal.find('.message'),
        $submits : $modal.find('.submit-button'),
        href     : $form.attr('data-href')
    };
}

var modal = createModal();
```

So you keep only one clean reference to the whole thing and you may access `modal.$modal` or `modal.$form`.

Comment: Do you think it would be sensible to add these (not quite sure how) or should I just keep them as variables on their own. Note that they always are together. In this example how could I add one of those objects and how could I access it later? BTW did you mean to write $form.$form or $modal.$form = ?

Comment: Personally, I use data only for objects over which I don't keep a reference. If you have only one $modal in your application, you could simply keep it in a complex object (last proposition). This is what I usually do.

Comment: I think his last method of creating `obj` to hold all your stuff in a single object is the most comprehensive.  You definitely don't want "to keep them as variables on their own" just floating around all willy nilly.  If you need to access this `obj` from anywhere, you can put it in the global scope (window) by doing `window.obj = {};` - of course, give it a better name than obj ;)

Comment: I like your last suggestion. How about if I was to have more than one modal. Could I store those in an array? In your example, did you miss out assigning href to the obj. ?

Comment: @Marilou Yes, I initially forgot href. And Yes, you can put them in an array. But you have to see how all this will fit in a coherent, readable and not verbose way in your application.

Comment: Thanks. You have been a great help to me !